# Android Studio: How to check rows in SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

I am trying to create a function that checks the total rows of the SQL table then
checks if 0 then it starts to count in 1.
if it is not then it gets the total row count then increment it by 1.

unfortunately I am experiencing this in logcat

> SQL Error :             com.cremcash.eloan                   E  No current row in the ResultSet.

Here is my code so far:

```java
try {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(SeqID) AS seq FROM EloanApp";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    if (rs.getString("seq").equals(0)){
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
        String seq_init = "1";
        formattedDate = df.format(c).concat(seq_init);
    }else{
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
        int intSeq = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("seq"));
        intSeq = intSeq + 1;
        formattedDate = df.format(c).concat(Integer.toString(intSeq));
    }
    textview.setText(formattedDate);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SQL Error : ", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Aside... You almost certainly don't want to have Android mobile devices directly querying SQL Servers over the open internet. Ignoring the security implications, the TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol it uses was designed 30+ years ago for LAN environments, is way too chatty, and so is too slow and unreliable over WANs. Have you considered putting a web API of some kind in front of your database?

Comment: I have but this project is only for the local server

Comment: You aren't calling method [next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) (of interface `java.sql.ResultSet`). I suggest a [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). By the way, does your version of Android not support the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)? You should use it rather than classes `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Oh yeah right. method next how silly of me -.-

Comment: There are better ways to check table rowcounts by querying the system DMVs